# How register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider on android

Tags: react-native

**strong text**
Please I need your help with this error which giving me on android emulator. I have spent plenty time to fix it and run my app but unfortunately I couldn't.

**strong text**

Here is screenshots of my Package json file

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^9.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: hi if put your error in question the viewer can help you Accurately and faster

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.